# Simple Rest API Account creation

Tags: php, api

I am trying to build Simple Rest api for my php website but i am having issue on creating the account

create.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
Authorization, X-Requested-With");
include_once 'database.php';
include_once 'data.php';
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$item = new emmanuel_api($db);


$item->user_name = $_GET['user_name'];
$item->user_pass = $_GET['user_pass'];
$item->user_email = $_GET['user_email'];
$item->full_name = $_GET['full_name'];
if($item->createUsers()){
echo 'Account created successfully.';
} else{
echo 'Account could not be created.';
}
?>
```

I think i am getting error on my Create.php please help me to resolve this issue

Also how i can convert this user_pass into MD5

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the error you’re getting

Comment: Unexpected character (A) at position 0

And here the link mate

https://codesmarters.xyz/create.php?user_name=ianrey&user_pass=ianrey@123&user_email=ian@gmail.com&full_name=Ian%20Rey%20Torres

Comment: Change this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");` to `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");`

Comment: I still getting same error mate :(

Comment: Show your errors so we can understand also you can understand - [PHP Errors and Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings)

Comment: Heres my error page bro
https://codesmarters.xyz/error_txt

Comment: There are 3 undefined indexes. Can you try commenting your headers just to test if it works, if the problem is there.

Comment: I have commenting all headers and i think still same, error

https://codesmarters.xyz/error_txt

Anyway heres my data.php mate i have change it into .txt temporary

https://codesmarters.xyz/data.txt

Comment: And heres the create.php

https://codesmarters.xyz/data.txt

Comment: Checkout on get url the index names should be correct.

Comment: Thanks mate, working now

Appreciate your help cheers